# Plot a plane that spanned by two vectors in python but raising zero division error

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plotly, geometry-surface

I have two vectors `v1 = np.array([-1, 1, 0])` and `v2 = np.array([0, 0, 1])`
and i want to plot a plane that spanned by these two vectors.

vectors **v1** and **v2**
[image: vectors v1 and v2]

```py
import numpy as np
from plotly import graph_objs as go 

v1 = np.array([-1, 1, 0])
v2 = np.array([0, 0, 1])

trace_v1 = go.Scatter3d(x=[0, v1[0]], y=[0, v1[1]], z=[0, v1[2]],mode='lines')
trace_v2 = go.Scatter3d(x=[0, v2[0]], y=[0, v2[1]], z=[0, v2[2]],mode='lines')

xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-1, 1, 10), np.linspace(-1, 1, 10))
cp = np.cross(v1, v2)                    # result is [1, 1, 0] 
zz = (-cp[0]*xx - cp[1]*yy) / cp[2]      # cp[2] is zero and raise an error because of zero division

surf = go.Surface(x=xx, y=yy, z=zz)

fig = go.Figure(data=[trace_v1, trace_v2, surf])
fig.show()
```

I try to use `np.cross()` between `v1` and `v2` for specifying `zz` but  `cp[2]` is zero and raise an error : `divide by zero encountered in true_divide`

***How should I specify `zz` ?***